# Vlookup across different sheets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to do a vlookup across several sheets within the same workbook:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,Regulares!J:L,3,0),ISNA(VLOOKUP('Temp Activos'!G:I,3,0),ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,'Temp JA'!G:I,3,0),VLOOKUP(A2,'Temp Fit'!G:I,3,0)))))
```

But I keep getting the error that I have too many arguments???

I would also like to make a macro to add this vlookup to a cell in one of my sheets (PS), and bring the formula down to the last row (fill handle) upon pressing a button, but first need to figure out why it wont work before plugging it into a code...

Comment: too many arguments for the IF()

Comment: So should I delete the IF?

Answer (score 0):

The `ISNA()` function just needs one parameter, so your parentheses are out of sync. If you are using Excel 2007 or later, you can more easily use the `IFERROR()` function which has two parameter, the second being the value to return in case of error, which would be the next `VLOOKUP` in your case.

Comment: Tried IF ERROR and get the same error message too many arguements:
`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Regulares!J:L,3,0),VLOOKUP(PS!A2,'Temp Activos'!G:I,3,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(PS!A2,'Temp JA'!G:I,3,0),VLOOKUP(PS!A2,'Temp Fit'!G:I,3,0)))`

Comment: The structure must be `IFERROR(VLOOKUP(), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(), ...))`. Try editing your formula with the function wizard (the fx sign left of the formula box) to sort out.